# Error: Could not find sqlite3-1.4.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I'm currently trying to get a run.rb file going, but I keep getting errors with sqlite3. When I type `bundle install`, I get this success message:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
Using i18n 1.5.3
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.2.2
Using activemodel 5.2.2
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.2
Using bundler 2.0.1
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using equatable 0.5.0
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using mustermann 1.0.3
Using necromancer 0.4.0
Using tty-color 0.4.3
Using pastel 0.7.2
Using pry 0.12.2
Using rack 2.0.6
Using rack-protection 2.0.5
Using require_all 2.0.0
Using tilt 2.0.9
Using sinatra 2.0.5
Using sinatra-activerecord 2.0.13
Using sqlite3 1.4.0
Using timers 4.3.0
Using tty-cursor 0.6.0
Using tty-screen 0.6.5
Using wisper 2.0.0
Using tty-reader 0.5.0
Using tty-prompt 0.18.1
Bundle complete! 7 Gemfile dependencies, 32 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

However, when running `ruby app/run.rb` I get this message:

```
Could not find sqlite3-1.4.0 in any of the sources
```

I've been trying for hours to figure out what the issue is, I've uninstalled and reinstalled sqlite3, bundle installed a million times, and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `rails server` to start the server or even `bundle exec rails server` to be sure to have the bundle loaded while starting the server? Why are you using `ruby app/run.rb` to start it?

Comment: 1.4.0 is a fresh version that came out 5 days ago. Have you tried using an earlier version?

Comment: I have tried requiring an earlier version, I get the same sqlite3 not found message: `Could not find sqlite3-1.3.13 in any of the sources`

Comment: @ulferts I'm using Sinatra currently

Comment: Well then, did you try running `bundle exec ruby run/app.rb`? I assume the gems are installed just fine but are not available to `require` at runtime. [bundle exec](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html) should fix that problem.

Comment: @ulferts I get the same exact message when using bundle exec, `Could not find sqlite3-1.3.13 in any of the sources`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Rails 5.2.2 you can sort out this problem by specifying proper version of sqlite3 in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

In 5-2-stable branch of Rails you can use sqlite 1.4, but in the 5.2.2 it causes the error.

Comment: As you see @AngeloS used Sinatra. Not Rails

Comment: I haven't noticed! However, I suppose that solution will be the same, because version of  `activerecord` is `5.2.2`. @AngeloS, let us know.

Comment: I added the 1.3.6 version to the gemfile, ran bundle install and now am seeing this error: `Could not find sqlite3-1.3.13 in any of the sources`

Answer (score 4):

You can try installing the `libsqlite3-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

or

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11'
```

Comment: How does this translate for Mac?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and fixed it by:
    First, I opened up the **Gemfile** in atom and changed the line  `gem 'sqlite3'` to `gem 'sqlite3' , '~>1.3.6'`.
    Second, I ran `gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.6` on terminal.
    Last, I ran `bundle install` on terminal.

This worked for me... goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that I didn't need `sqlite` to run my app.

So, I opened the `Gemfile` and deleted `gem 'sqlite3' ...` from it and everything worked fine.